# How to remove the content of handwriting in a picture？

Tags: opencv3.0

I'm doing image cutting, but handwritten content always interferes with me.The handwritten content made me can not separate different rows. Always it makes me 
separate the two rows into the same row. So i want to know how can i solve this problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, you are expected to show your attempt first and show where you are encountering a problem, please go through [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimum complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you are looking for theory other stack exchange sites will be better suited.

Comment: which language and platform are you doing this in?

Comment: both c++ and python @JohnLord